# Function to slice indices in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have two index arrays and I want to return all the indices in between, like a slice function, manually it would look like this:

```
ind1 = np.array([2,6])
ind2 = np.array([2,3])

final = np.array([[2,2,2], [4,5,6]])
```

Since the axis along which to slice is not fixed, I came up with this:

```
def index_slice(ind1,ind2):
    return np.indices( 1 + ind1 - ind2 ) + ind2[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]

final = index_slice(ind1,ind2)
```

However, this relies on `1 + ind1 > ind2`  and it includes the last index as well (not pythonic).  Would anyone know of a function that does this, or a cleaner implementation?
Thank you in advance. 
Diego

P.S. To give some background of where this idea came from.  I am considering submatrices of a matrix, and I want to have access to them from the indices in two corners.  Due to the nature of the problem, the given corners don't always have the same orientation as you can see in @pelson's answer.

Comment: So for each member of `ind1` and `ind2` you want a row in `final` containing the interpolated indices?  Will `ind1` and `ind2` always be two values long?  Also, like phihag says, it will encourage people to answer your future questions if you accept answers to previous questions.

Comment: Thank you for the note.  While I was trying to add some comments, I hadn't realized to mark a correct answer, so yeah... that's much better.

Comment: As I thought about `ind1` and `ind2`, they can be two indices in any ND-array, and `final` should fill up the matrix between them... like in pelson's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have it in a one liner, but something like the following will reproduce the results you seem to be asking for:

```
def index_slice(arr1, arr2):
    lens = np.abs(arr1 - arr2)
    if not all((lens == max(lens)) | (lens == 0)):
        raise ValueError('The number of indices in some dimensions were inconsistent. Array lengths were %r' % lens)

    max_len = lens.max()
    result = np.empty((len(lens), max_len), dtype=np.int32)

    for dim, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(arr1, arr2)):
        if a == b:
            result[dim, :] = a
        elif a > b:
            result[dim, :] = np.arange(a, b, -1)
        else:
            result[dim, :] = np.arange(a, b)

    return result
```

For instance:

```
>>> ind1 = np.array([2, 6])
>>> ind2 = np.array([2, 3])
>>> print index_slice(ind1, ind2)
[[2 2 2]
 [6 5 4]]


>>> ind1 = np.array([2, 6, 1])
>>> ind2 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> print index_slice(ind1, ind2)
[[2 2 2]
 [6 5 4]
 [1 2 3]]
```

However, asking this question raises my suspicion that you are probably doing something which could be done in a simpler way if you were to share your upstream logic.

HTH

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the feedback.